# call of distinct and map together throws NPE in spark library

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, apache-spark

I am unsure if this is a bug, so if you do something like this

```
// d:spark.RDD[String]
d.distinct().map(x => d.filter(_.equals(x)))
```

you will get a Java NPE. However if you do a `collect` immediately after `distinct`, all will be fine.

I am using [spark](http://www.spark-project.org) 0.6.1.

Comment: Are you sure the distinct is no returning any null value? Collect on collections uses a partial function that may not match null. In your case you are using a method call on an object that may be null.

Comment: @Thomas I am pretty sure I do not have null in d. Besides, I can do d.distinct().foreach(println), which prints out all the distinct values in d successfully.

Comment: Then the stack trace may hint on where the NPE was born.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, distinct.foreach is fine, but npe was thrown immediately after that when program started to map the rdd returned from distinct

Comment: Try protecting from NPE, for example map(x => d.filter(y => if(y!= null) y.equals(x) else false) or better yet (x => d.filter(x == _)). Maybe d.filter allows null values.

Comment: @Thomas I just found out d is actually null inside map closure..., so npe really complaints null.filter not _.equals(null)

Comment: Any thnoughts? d is no way a null object, otherwise d.distinct() would fail in the first place. can anybody shed some lights on why it becomes null inside map??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spark does not support nested RDDs or user-defined functions that refer to other RDDs, hence the NullPointerException; see [this thread on the `spark-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spark-users/KC1UJEmUeg8/discussion).

It looks like your current code is trying to group the elements of `d` by value; you can do this efficiently with the `groupBy()` [RDD](http://spark-project.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#spark.RDD) method:

```
scala> val d = sc.parallelize(Seq("Hello", "World", "Hello"))
d: spark.RDD[java.lang.String] = spark.ParallelCollection@55c0c66a

scala> d.groupBy(x => x).collect()
res6: Array[(java.lang.String, Seq[java.lang.String])] = Array((World,ArrayBuffer(World)), (Hello,ArrayBuffer(Hello, Hello)))
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the windowing example provided in the Spark 1.3.0 stream programming guide

```
val dataset: RDD[String, String] = ...
val windowedStream = stream.window(Seconds(20))...
val joinedStream = windowedStream.transform { rdd => rdd.join(dataset) }
```

SPARK-5063 causes the example to fail since the join is being called from within the transform method on an RDD