# Graphx: I've got NullPointerException inside mapVertices

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use graphx. For now I just launchs it locally.
I've got NullPointerException in these few lines. First println works well, and second one fails.

```
..........
val graph: Graph[Int, Int] = Graph(users, relationships)
println("graph.inDegrees = " + graph.inDegrees.count) // this line works well
graph.mapVertices((id, v) => {
  println("graph.inDegrees = " + graph.inDegrees.count) // but this one fails
  42 // doesn't mean anything
}).vertices.collect
```

And it does not matter which method of 'graph' object I call. But 'graph' is not null inside 'mapVertices'.

```
Exception failure in TID 2 on host localhost: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl.mapReduceTriplets(GraphImpl.scala:168)
org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps.degreesRDD(GraphOps.scala:72)
org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps.inDegrees$lzycompute(GraphOps.scala:49)
org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps.inDegrees(GraphOps.scala:48)
ololo.MyOwnObject$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcIJI$sp(Twitter.scala:42)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproduced using GraphX 2.10 on Spark 1.0.2. I'll give you a workaround and then explain what I think is happening. This works for me:

```
val c = graph.inDegrees.count
graph.mapVertices((id, v) => {
  println("graph.inDegrees = " + c)
}).vertices.collect
```

In general, Spark gets prickly when you try to access an entire `RDD` or other distributed object (like a `Graph`) in code that's intended to execute in parallel on a single partition, like the function you're passing into `mapVertices`. But it's also usually a **bad idea** even when you can get it to work. (As a separate matter, as you've seen, when it doesn't work it tends to result in really unhelpful behavior.)

The vertices of a `Graph` are represented as an `RDD`, and the function you pass into `mapVertices` runs locally in the appropriate partitions, where it is given access to local vertex data: `id` and `v`. You really don't *want* the entire graph to be copied to each partition. In this case you just need to broadcast a scalar to each partition, so pulling it out solved the problem and the broadcast is really cheap.

There are tricks in the Spark APIs for accessing more complex objects in such a situation, but if you use them carelessly they will destroy your performance because they'll tend to introduce lots of communication. Often people are tempted to use them because they don't understand the computation model, rather than because they really need to, although that does happen too.

Answer (score 1):

Spark does not support nested RDDs or user-defined functions that refer to other RDDs, hence the NullPointerException; see [this thread on the `spark-users` mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spark-users/KC1UJEmUeg8/discussion).  In this case, you're attempting to call `count()` on a `Graph` (which performs an action on a Spark RDD) from inside of a `mapVertices()` transformation, leading to a NullPointerException when `mapVertices()` attempts to access data structures that are only callable by the Spark driver.

In a nutshell, only the Spark driver can launch new Spark jobs; you can't call actions on RDDs from inside of other RDD actions.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793399/590203 for another example of this issue.