# String filter using Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

input.csv:

> 200,300,889,767,9908,7768,9090
>
> 300,400,223,4456,3214,6675,333
>
> 234,567,890
>
> 123,445,667,887

What I want:
Read input file and compare with set "123,200,300" if match found, gives matching data
200,300 (from 1 input line)

300 (from 2 input line)

123 (from 4 input line)

What I wrote:

```
  import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  object sparkApp {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("CountingSheep")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    def parseLine(invCol: String) : RDD[String]  = {
      println(s"INPUT, $invCol")
      val inv_rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(invCol.toString))
      val bs_meta_rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("123,200,300"))
      return inv_rdd.intersection(bs_meta_rdd)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val filePathName = "hdfs://xxx/tmp/input.csv"
      val rawData = sc.textFile(filePathName)
      val datad = rawData.map{r => parseLine(r)}
    }
  }
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Please suggest where I went wrong

Comment: How did you run your program?
Have you Your compiled and packaged the jar already?

Comment: Yes I compiled and package the jar ::   spark-submit --class "sparkApp" --master local  --num-executors 2     --driver-memory 1g     --executor-memory 1g     --executor-cores 1 /home/spark_app/sparkApp/target/scala-2.10/sparkapp_2.10-1.0.jar

Comment: When I ran the code, I got the exception

Comment: can you put your maven or sbt file here?

Comment: simple.sbt
 
 name := "SparkApp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.2",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.28"
)
OR anything else is requried?

Comment: Seem your sbt file is not good. Because I already compiled and ran code in my machine already (ran well). 
I put you a reference here https://gist.github.com/giaosudau/e62ab2261de9f2b740f7d61bcba76314

Comment: Error while compiling code
[hdfs@app193 sparkApp]$ sbt compile
/home/spark_app/sparkApp/simple.sbt:50: error: not found: value assemblyJarName
assemblyJarName in assembly := "impression.jar"
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

Comment: you should use sbt assembly plugin https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: So do you get an exception, or a type error? You've said both now. If exception, please provide the stack trace

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul the OP is trying to run actions on RDDs (SPARK-5063) I was watching the conversation to see where they were heading.

Comment: Ah yes, looked at the code now! And yet @giaosudau says the code compiled and ran!

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul that's why I didn't comment before. I'm sorry, I'm wicked sometimes :)

Comment: SO How we can achieve ?

Comment: How do we achieve what ? Your code doesn't make much sense. Would you care to explain what you are trying to do with you code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **For simple answer, why we are making it so complex? In this case we don't require UDF.**

This is your input data:

```
200,300,889,767,9908,7768,9090|AAA
300,400,223,4456,3214,6675,333|BBB
234,567,890|CCC
123,445,667,887|DDD
```

and you have to match it with `123,200,300`

```
val matchSet = "123,200,300".split(",").toSet
val rawrdd = sc.textFile("D:\\input.txt")
rawrdd.map(_.split("|"))
      .map(arr => arr(0).split(",").toSet.intersect(matchSet).mkString(",") + "|" + arr(1))
      .foreach(println)
```

Your output:

```
300,200|AAA
300|BBB
|CCC
123|DDD
```

Comment: You split input line with "," 200,300,889,767,9908,7768,9090. As per requriement this is a single column. Dont split it. If you want to split, use \t

Comment: EI know that @Manish, this is a single column. Please try to understand my code. I just concise your code in terms of performance as you know user defined function is expensive in spark. Try to run this code. Hope, it will resolved your issue.

Comment: Hi @ManishSaraf , I have just updated this code. Please check and let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved. This is very simple.

```
val pfile = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/6mjxi2uz1492576337920/input.csv")
case class pSchema(id: Int, pName: String)
val pDF = pfile.map(_.split("\t")).map(p => pSchema(p(0).toInt,p(1).trim())).toDF()
pDF.select("id","pName").show()
```

[image]

Define UDF

```
val findP = udf((id: Int,
                    pName: String
                    ) => {
  val ids = Array("123","200","300")
  var idsFound : String = ""
  for (id  <- ids){
    if (pName.contains(id)){
      idsFound = idsFound + id + ","
    }
  }
  if (idsFound.length() > 0) {
    idsFound = idsFound.substring(0,idsFound.length -1)
  }    
 idsFound
})
```

Use UDF in withCoulmn()

```
pDF.select("id","pName").withColumn("Found",findP($"id",$"pName")).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can't be done the way you are doing it.

Spark does not support nested RDDs (see [SPARK-5063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063)).

> Spark does not support nested RDDs or performing Spark actions inside of transformations; this usually leads to NullPointerExceptions (see SPARK-718 as one example). The confusing NPE is one of the most common sources of Spark questions on StackOverflow:
>
> - [call of distinct and map together throws NPE in spark library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770218/call-of-distinct-and-map-together-throws-npe-in-spark-library/14130534#14130534)
> - [NullPointerException in Scala Spark, appears to be caused be collection type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type/23793399#23793399)
> - [Graphx: I've got NullPointerException inside mapVertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997558/graphx-ive-got-nullpointerexception-inside-mapvertices/26003674#26003674)
>     (those are just a sample of the ones that I've answered personally; there are many others).
>
> I think we can detect these errors by adding logic to RDD to check whether sc is null (e.g. turn sc into a getter function); we can use this to add a better error message.