# Spark - Lost task in stage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Any ideas why this would not work?

```
val m = sc.union(sc.parallelize(0 until 10).map(n => sc.parallelize(n until 20))).collect()
```

I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm more interested in why it does not work.

results: http://pastebin.com/FuiKFMMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to invoke methods on SparkContext from inside of code that runs in an action or transformation (the `sc.parallelize` call inside of the `map` call, in this case).  SparkContext methods can only be invoked from the driver, not inside of code that might run in Spark executors (e.g. actions and transformations).

I have a Spark pull request that adds better error messages in this scenario: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3884.

See also: [NullPointerException in Scala Spark, appears to be caused be collection type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type/23793399#23793399)