# NULL Pointer Exception, while creating DF inside foreach()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have to read certain files from S3, so I created a CSV containing path of those files on S3. I am reading created CSV file using below code:

```
val listofFilesRDD = sparkSession.read.textFile("s3://"+ file)
```

This is working fine.
Then I am trying to read each of those paths and create dataframe like:

```
listofFilesRDD.foreach(iter => {
  val pathDF = sparkSession.read
    .schema(testSchema)
    .option("headers", true)
    .csv("s3://"+iter)

  pathDF.printSchema()
})
```

but, the above code gives NullPointerException.

So, How can I fix the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the above problem as below you simple create Array of s3 file paths and iterate over that array and create DF inside that as below

```
val listofFilesRDD = sparkSession.read.textFile("s3://"+ file)
val listOfPaths = listofFilesRDD.collect()

    listOfPaths.foreach(iter => {
    val pathDF = sparkSession.read
    .schema(testSchema)
    .option("headers", true)
    .csv("s3://"+iter)


pathDF.printSchema()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a RDD inside a RDD ! Thats the sole rule ! You have to do something else to make your logic work !

You can find more about it here : [NullPointerException in Scala Spark, appears to be caused be collection type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone encounter DataFrame problem , can solve this problem.

```
   def parameterjsonParser(queryDF:DataFrame,spark:SparkSession): Unit ={
        queryDF.show()
        val otherDF=queryDF.collect()
        otherDF.foreach { row =>
          row.toSeq.foreach { col =>
            println(col)
            mainJsonParser(col.toString,spark)
          }
        }
```

Thank you @Sandeep Purohit