# Unable to access RDD in Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a simple RDD created from a seq as follows.

```
val testRDD = sc.parallelize(list.toSeq,size);
```

While iterating through the rows, it throws a null exception error in cluster mode. It works fine in client mode.

```
testRDD.foreach(row => {
         logger.info("Row index "  + row.index.toString() );
       
    })
```

testRDD.count() and testRDD.partitions.size returns the appropriate results. When collect() action is performed foreach works fine, however I do not want collect in this scenario since the RDD needs to be distributed among nodes.

Comment: Are you sure it was not related to [Spark not supporting nesting of RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type)?

Answer (score 0):

Able to identify the issue is related to logger object not RDD. Able to proceed after removing the logger and the broadcast other required variables.