# Nesting of RDD's in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Referring to this question : [NullPointerException in Scala Spark, appears to be caused be collection type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793117/nullpointerexception-in-scala-spark-appears-to-be-caused-be-collection-type)

Answer states "Spark doesn't support nesting of RDDs (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130534/590203 for another occurrence of the same problem), so you can't perform transformations or actions on RDDs inside of other RDD operations."

This code :

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List(1 , 2, 3))

def fun1(n : Int) = {
    fun2(n)
}

def fun2(n: Int) = {
    n + 1
}

x.map(v => fun1(v)).take(1)
```

prints :

```
Array[Int] = Array(2)
```

This is correct.

But does this not disagree with "can't perform transformations or actions on RDDs inside of other RDD operations." since a nested action is occurring on an RDD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the linked question `d.filter(...)` returns an RDD, so the type of

```
d.distinct().map(x => d.filter(_.equals(x)))
```

is `RDD[RDD[String]]`. This isn't allowed, but it doesn't happen in your code. If I understand the answer right, you can't refer to `d` or other RDDs inside `map` as well even if you don't get `RDD[RDD[SomeType]]` in the end.