# If I can use a user-defined function to a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use a md5 function to RDD[(String,Array[Double])], but there is an Error
of Null pointer exception. And I found the question on stack overflow.[call of distinct and map together throws NPE in spark library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770218/call-of-distinct-and-map-together-throws-npe-in-spark-library).

my code:

```
def md5(s: String) = {
    MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes).
           map("%02x".format(_)).mkString.substring(0,8)
  }

val rdd=sc.makeRDD(Array(1,8,6,4,9,3,76,4))//.collect().foreach(println)
val rdd2 = rdd.map(r=>(r+"s",Array(1.0,2.0)))

rdd2.map{
  case(a,b) => (md5(a)+"_"+a,b)
}.foreach(println)
```

in the local mode, it's ok, but in the cluster mode, it's error.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can I have another way to do this? thx :)

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException                       
    at no1.no1$.no1$no1$$md5$1(no1.scala:139)
    at no1.no1$$anonfun$8.apply(no1.scala:143)
    at no1.no1$$anonfun$8.apply(no1.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at no1.no1$.main(no1.scala:141)
    at no1.no1.main(no1.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

the code above is an example, but this code seems to be right. I am confused.

Comment: Question you've linked is not relevant here. Could you provide __full__ traceback? `NullPointerException` without context is not very meaningful. Moreover this code seem to work just fine both in local mode and on cluster.

Comment: the reason maybe is my hbase's conf SCAN_COLUMNS has some problems...

Answer (score 0):

I see no way for the RDD to provide a `null` string to your MD5 function, and the failure is clearly inside it:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at no1.no1$.no1$no1$$md5$1(no1.scala:139) <-- here!

My money would be that the static call `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` is returning `null` on the executors. That or the `.digest` call. Check for conditions on which that can happen, maybe the inputs your are trying locally do no contain the failure cases.