# Convert RDD[RDD[T]] to RDD[T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda

I think the title pretty much sums up what I am trying to do here. I have the following piece of code

```scala
implicit val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val result = RDD[RDD[GenericRecord]] = sc.parallelize(dates).map { date => 
    val foo: RDD[GenericRecord] = readSomething(...)
    foo
}
```

I want to convert `result` to an RDD of `GenericRecord` but `foo` is not `Traversable` so that I can use `flatMap`. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130534/6566916), Spark does not support nested RDDs. So even if I was able to flat map this somehow it would fail on runtime. What I ended up doing is the following:

```scala
implicit val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val partials = IndexedSeq[RDD[GenericRecord]] = dates.map { date => 
    val foo: RDD[GenericRecord] = readSomething(...)
    foo
}

val result:RDD[GenericRecord] = sc.union(partials)
```